# Unable to fetch parse data using JSON

Tags: android, json

I am learning to parse data from a URL using JSON.
In the following code,i am URLConnection class object to get data from a URL.

The code doesn't show any error,but on executing it produces a blank screen.
I am unable to understand why its happening.

Here is the code.

```
package com.example.asad.parse;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tv;
    int count=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d("asd", "calling call");

        new GetJson().execute("http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json");
//        try{
//
//                call();
//            }catch(Exception e) {
//
//        }

    }
    public class GetJson extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            Log.d("asd", params[0]);
//            Log.d("asd","outside try");
            StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
            URL url= null;
            try {
                Log.d("asd","inside call");
                url = new URL(params[0]);

                URLConnection tc = url.openConnection();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        tc.getInputStream()));

                Log.d("asd","above while.");
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    Log.d("asd","inside while.");
                    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(line);
                    for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                      Log.d("asd",jo.toString());
                    }
                }
//
//            tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
//            tv.setText(sb);
                Log.d("asd",sb.toString());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("asd", "I am in catch");

            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try to run the url into the browser to see if the json shows up correctly?

Comment: What are Log.d("asd", params[0]) and Log.d("asd",jo.toString()) outputs?

Comment: params[0] prints the URL which i specified and since the code is not able to enter into the while loop that's why jo.toString() isn't printing anything.

Comment: @ helldawg, yes the URL is valid,i checked it.

Comment: Do you have internet access permission?

Comment: Don't read the response line by line to parse each one individually (unless you're absolutely certain that's the format of the response, and that would be strange).  It's much safer to read the whole response into a string and then send that whole string to your json parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended for JSON to use StringBuilder.
There could be few things wrong with your code:

1. Permission in your mainfest.xml

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   ```
2. Reading line by line is not perfect solution for JSON.

Use static methods to return full json text from URL

```
public static String getData(String uri) {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(uri);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append((line + "\n"));
        }

        return sb.toString();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After that you can loop through your json text by addressing the right array/object.
Inside your AsyncTask:

```
String jsonText = getData("http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json");
try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonText);
        ...
}
```

after that start reading json objects

Answer (score 0):

update a view, have a textview and setText after getting the response.

Comment: the problem is that code isn't able to enter in the while loop. I just want to know why??

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks okay according to this [JAVA DOC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html)

Try to check your Manifest file for [internet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET) permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You put a log statement in your catch clause but you don't look at what its writing...
First build the whole string using the StringBuffer and BufferedReader and only after that convert it to a json array or object.

```
URLConnection tc = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(tc.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(sb.toString());
        for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
            Log.d("asd", jo.toString());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```